# JQuery toggle is hiding the div element

Tags: jquery, html, css, toggle

I'm having some trouble with developing an expand-shrink toggle div.

My goal is to click the div and make it bigger, clicking it again and get it back to the original height.

I got this JQuery script but it is causing the entire div to disappear.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".noticia").toggle(function(){
        $(".noticia").css('height', '600px');
    }, function () {
        $(".noticia").css('height', '420px');
    });
});
```

and the html

```
    <div class="noticia">
        <img src="img/noticias/novo_rosto.jpg">
        <div class="descricao">
            <span class="data">21 de Janeiro de 2014</span>
            <h1>Fernando Mendes é o novo rosto da OPTICENTER</h1>
            <p class="preview">
                Os seus óculos ao preço certo!<br>
                É o slogan da nova campanha do grupo e é inspirado na aposta contínua da OPTICENTER em apresentar aos seus clientes os óculos a um preço fechado...
            </p>
            <p class="full">
                Os seus óculos ao preço certo!<br>
                É o slogan da nova campanha do grupo e é inspirado na aposta contínua da OPTICENTER em apresentar aos seus clientes os óculos a um preço fechado, numa oferta de mais de 1000 modelos à escolha com lentes certificadas e de fabrico nacional.<br>
                Confiança, Seriedade, Profissionalismo e Credibilidade são os valores defendidos pela OPTICENTER que acredita serem transmitidos na integra por Fermando Mendes, um dos rostos mais conhecidos e populares da televisão nacional.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I believe the css is not the cause of the problem, but just in case:

```
.noticia{
    width: 280px;
    height: 420px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    background: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.1s linear, border-bottom 0.1s linear;
       -moz-transition: background 0.1s linear, border-bottom 0.1s linear;
         -o-transition: background 0.1s linear, border-bottom 0.1s linear;
            transition: background 0.1s linear, border-bottom 0.1s linear;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.noticia .descricao{
    width: 278px;
    height: 235px;
    margin: -3px 0 10px 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #EEE;
    border-left: 1px solid #EEE;
    -webkit-transition: border-right 0.1s linear, border-left 0.1s linear;
       -moz-transition: border-right 0.1s linear, border-left 0.1s linear;
         -o-transition: border-right 0.1s linear, border-left 0.1s linear;
            transition: border-right 0.1s linear, border-left 0.1s linear;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: auto;
}
.noticia .descricao .data{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #B7B7B7;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
       -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
         -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
            transition: color 0.1s linear;
}
.noticia .descricao h1{
    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
       -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
         -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
            transition: color 0.1s linear;
    margin: 30px 0 0 0;
}
.noticia .descricao p{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
    color: #B7B7B7;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.1s linear;
       -moz-transition: color 0.1s linear;
         -o-transition: color 0.1s linear;
            transition: color 0.1s linear;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 19px;
}
.preview{
    visibility: visible;
}
.full{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.noticia:hover{
    background: #606062;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #606062;
}
.noticia:hover .descricao{
    border-right: 1px solid #606062;
    border-left: 1px solid #606062;
}
.noticia:hover .descricao .data, .noticia:hover .descricao h1, .noticia:hover .descricao p{
    color: #FFF;
}
```

I'm not really much of a programer so I would really appreciate some tips to get this solved and why is it happening.

Comment: `toggle()` event you are using is **[deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)**. New `,toggle()` hides/shows the element.

Comment: ↑↑↑ removed from 1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`toggle() (Event)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)** event is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Current **[`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** function changes the state of the element.

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".noticia").click(function(){
        $(this).css('height', $(this).css('height') == "420px" ? "600px" : "420px");
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! But can you help me once again? I also want to toggle visibilities and heights INSIDE of .noticia div. I did on my own using the classes names instead of "this" but it is toggling every .noticia div, I want to just toggle the one I'm clicking. Ideas?

Comment: For just the *one you are clicking* you need to use `$(this)`. It gives current context/current element clicked

Comment: @Shawnak D, take a look at my html, I want to toggle the display of the `p` `.preview` and `.full`. how can I do it? something like `$(this .preview)` ?

Comment: `$('.preview', this).toggle()`  and `$('.full',this).toggle()`

Comment: you're a freaking god.

Answer (score 4):

[jQuery toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) shows or hides an element, it doesn't toggle a function.

To toggle height like you would like to, it would probably be best to introduce a new CSS class into your CSS file and use [jQuery toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to either add or remove the class. So:

JS changes to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".noticia").toggleClass('large');
});
```

CSS addition of class:

```
.noticia.large {
    height: 600px;
}
```