# Trying to toggle animate div square (can't figure out error)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

So, I'm using this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tJugd/3427/

As  a basis to animate the squares in this carousel (all have class="carouselbutton":

http://jsfiddle.net/YbrX3/1035/

JavaScript

```
$('.carouselbutton').toggle(function(){
        $(this).animate({height:'300',width:'300'});
    },function(){
        $(this).animate({height:'80',width:'80'});
});
```

It's not working. I'm wondering if some of the other class labels are interfering. I would greatly appreciate anyone's input!

(Side note: I also can't figure out how to vertically align the text within the squares. When I use `vertical-align:middle`, it changes the shape of the square. I'm not sure if I'm going to get in trouble for tagging a second onto this, though.)

Comment: `toggle(fn,fn)` is deprecated. So depends on version of jQuery you are using. Second demo is loaded with mootools which definitely won't work. Works here using older jQuery http://jsfiddle.net/mh5087qd/

Comment: **[`toggle() (Event)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)** is deprecated. I **[answered a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30194754/3639582)** here. MIght help.

Comment: Thanks - that was a helpful post, Shaunak. I updated it for JQuery 1.11.1. Now, the square expands, but it doesn't contract when clicked a second time. http://jsfiddle.net/mh5087qd/4/

Comment: For the vertical aligning, one method is to set the line-height to the same height as the box, e.g.
`line-height:100px;` and in the animate method: `$(this).animate({height:'300',width:'300',lineHeight:'300px'});`

You could also have a .large class and use the jQuery toggleClass method.

Comment: @JasonX Check your updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/mh5087qd/67/